# Laravel eloquent groupy by date, return also empty/zero rows

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I successfully group by datetime (each hour) with this:

```
$adminActivities = Activity::whereBetween('created_at', [$data->from_date, $data->to_date])->where('user_id', $data->admin_id)->get()
->groupBy(function($date) {
    return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('Y-m-d H'); 
});
```

Example results, which I get atm. for 1 day:

```
2019-10-18 10: [{…}]
2019-10-18 15: (15) [{…}, ...]
```

In the example we see, that it found 1 result for 10 o'clock and 15 results for 15 o'clock.

I use the results to create a chart with chart js.

**I need all the hours of the day, that is what I want:**

```
2019-10-18 00: []
2019-10-18 01: []
2019-10-18 02: []
2019-10-18 03: []
...
2019-10-18 10: [{…}]
2019-10-18 15: (15) [{…}, ...]
...
2019-10-18 23: []
```

**What should I do to make it return also the zero results for each hour?**

I tried a different syntax, but the results are the same:

```
$adminActivities = Activity::whereBetween('created_at', [$data->from_date, $data->to_date])->where('user_id', $data->admin_id)
->selectRaw("COUNT(*) views, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H') date")->groupBy('date')->get();
```

Comment: Empty results, for example if it would not find a single row for 2019-10-18 00

Comment: No I dont get it, that is what I want. Its an example of the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly there is a more elegant solution, but you can create an array containing all desired hours and fill them with your query results, like:

```
 $start = Carbon::create($data->from_date);
 $end = Carbon::create($data->to_date);

 $adminActivities = Activity::whereBetween(
     'created_at', [$start->toDateTimeString(), $end->toDateTimeString()])
     ->where('user_id', $data->admin_id)->get()
     ->groupBy(function($date) {
         return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('Y-m-d H'); 
     });

 $hours = [];   

 /*for ($i = 0; $i < $start->diffInHours($end); $i++) 
 {  
     $key = $start->format('Y-m-d H');
     $hours[$key] = isset($adminActivities[$key]) ? $adminActivities[$key]->toArray() : [];
     $start->addHour();
 }*/

 dd($hours);
```

This works for @Roman:

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < 25) {
    $key = $start->format('Y-m-d ' . $i);
    $hours[$key] = isset($adminActivities[$key]) ? $adminActivities[$key]->toArray() : [];
    $i += 1;
}
```

Comment: You have some errors in your code, e.g. `$users` should be `$adminActivities`. Also in your example hours stop at 11:00. It needs to stop at 23:00. I am also working on a similar approach.

Comment: yeah, it is because I was working in another thing here and I stopped to help you. Now fixed!

Comment: Its still showing only half the day (00:00 - 11:00). I need (00:00 - 23:00). Thanks so far.

Comment: Probably because of PM/AM. I made a workaround, let me edit your code.